# Select element after adding it

Tags: jquery, element, selector

I have the following code

```
    img.after('<li></li>');
```

Which works correctly and add the "li" element. Now I want to select the "li" element; it doesn't have any class or ID, but I want to select it just after creating it, so I'm able to use it (for example mynewli.addClass()) as a jquery element.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `.insertAfter()` to be able to **chain**, which is the **heart** of `jQuery`.

```
var $newLI = $('<li/>').insertAfter(img).addClass('yourclass');
```

**edit**

In respect of your comment, use

```
img.next('li');
```

onto your cached `img` element. Note that this won't guarantee that you select a specific
element, it'll just select that next `li` element. So I still suggest to use `.insertAfter()` and cache that newly created item into a variable, to access later.

Reference: [.insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)

Comment: Good solution, but this won't let me select the item again (only on that chain)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method

```
img.next();
```

to find the next sibling of `img`, which should be your added `li` element.

Answer (score 0):

use next():

http://api.jquery.com/next/

assuming that img is a JQuery DOM object:

```
img.next().addClass('whatever');
```